# awesome: change notifications

Tags: ubuntu, awesome-wm

Running Ubuntu 16.04, I installed awesome-wm and I notice the notifications don't look correct. Out of the box with 0 configuration awesome-wm doesn't seem to be using the correct notifications daemon. I tried installing dunst, and while it works in Unity, there is no difference in awesome. How can I change the notification daemon or at least customize the look of the notifications awesome uses? I wouldn't even need to customize it normally, but for some reason the icons in the notification are huge, looks like their unscaled full resolution.

Comment: You should consider adding a screenshot. We can't guess if your problem is related to your preferences or something we can actually fix. Also, the Awesome WM version would help.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit summer 2019:** The notification system has been rewritten. For now, unless very good arguments are made on the bug tracker, I consider external notification deamons to be unsupported. The new notification system offers great flexibility and feature parity with every alternative I am aware of. More information [here](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/core_components/naughty.notification.html) and [here](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/popups_and_bars/naughty.layout.box.html). Note that those features require the (yet to be released as of this comment) AwesomeWM v4.4.

Duplicate of https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/1862

There is a "fix" in one of my branch, but it isn't merged yet (and certainly wasn't merged when 16.04 was released).

To use a different notification daemon than Awesome default one, comment the `require("naughty")` line in `rc.lua`.

Awesome 4.3 will have a workaround with the new `beautiful.notification_icon_size` theme variable, but it isn't released yet.

Comment: Fixed, thanks (literal typo, "u" and "i" are next to each other)

Comment: Commenting out `require('naughty')` and restarting awesome immediately fixed the problem.

Comment: Both first two links 404.